# ElasticSearch drops a field in indexing with Java

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, indexing

I recently come across with this problem with ElasticSearch indexing in Java. When writing a record into ElasticSearch from serialized json byte array, one of the fields is missing or dropped.

The pretty-printed `byte[] content` example:

```
{
   "created_at": 1468390585000,
   "name": "Lucy",
   "id": 123,
   "message": "Hi how are you",
   "thread_id": 456,
   "user_id": 789
}
```

The Java index call:

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX, TYPE, data.getId().toString())
      .source(content)
      .versionType(VersionType.EXTERNAL)
      .version(data.getCreatedAt().getTime());
```

In the indexing, all the fields are present in result except the `name`:

```
GET /my_index/post/123

{
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "post",
    "_id": "123",
    "_version": 1468390585000,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "id": 123,
        "user_id": 456,
        "created_at": 1468390585000,
        "message": "Hi how are you",
        "thread_id": 789
    }
}
```

`name` is a new field I newly-created. It is present in the mapping:

```
{  
   "my_index":{  
      "mappings":{  
         "post":{  
            "properties":{  
               "created_at":{  
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "name":{  
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "id":{  
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "message":{  
                  "type":"string",
                  "analyzer":"english_text"
               },
               "thread_id":{  
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "user_id":{  
                  "type":"long"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Other fields were created with the creation of the `post` type.

I suspect that there is some kinda of filtering in writing/indexing the data in Java API. I can `PUT` the same json in command line and see `name` included in result. It seems only the Java API is dropping the field. But I am not sure.

If you have any ideas, I'll appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there are existing documents without the new `name` attributes. Therefore inserting a document with the same `id` and `version` with amended `name` will get version conflicts. The `PUT` from command line works because it is a new document. It has nothing to do with Java.

I should use `update` API to do partial update.